# Why is parseInt() so much slower than *1 in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox

I have a value stored as a string, and I know it will always be a whole number. But I need it as a number, so I was doing `n = n * 1`. Then I thought "hmm, I should probably just use `parseInt()`. Then I ran some jsperf tests, and the results in Firefox were interesting:

http://jsperf.com/parseintx1

Across the board, it appears the operations are pretty similar, except in Firefox, using `*1` is exceptionally faster. What's going on here?

---

**Edit**

Someone made the base 10 test, and updated the tests overall. Click away on this one too to give some extra feedback: http://jsperf.com/parseintx1/2

Comment: Add `, 10` to force base 10.  (I don't have Firefox right now)

Comment: As all the variables are statically initialized, maybe Rhino optimizes the code before execution. For example, the line `d = d * 1;` does nothing and can be stripped. The rest can be rewritten.

Comment: ParseInt was faster for me in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @j08691: Seconded. Got the same result

Comment: @j08691 Really? Same test? Link?

Comment: @hookedonwinter - really. Not sure what link you want since I just used your jsperf test.

Comment: @j08691 ah cool. thought maybe you made a new test. thanks for clicking.

Comment: @Imp Rhino is not the JavaScript engine in Firefox.  It's "JägerMonkey".  Rhino is a Java implementation of JavaScript.

Comment: Casting to a number and using `parseInt` are different operations. Instead of worrying about which is faster, worry about which is desired for the solution.

Comment: Interesting. In chrome, *1 is 43% slower while parseInt is 99% slower in firefox.

Comment: It must have something to do with the test itself. @ http://jsperf.com/tilde-against-parseint-and/2 `parseInt` outperfoms all (FF 14.01)

Comment: I'd phrase it as "why is *1 so much faster in FF than anything else on any browser" based on that graph.

Comment: If you think about it, it's a pretty easy static analysis problem. The parser can tell that the local variable will have that string value, and that it's being used in an idempotent expression with a constant. Thus, the code it generates can just be to initialize the variables to the numeric versions of the strings, or possibly even generate no code at all since there are no possible side-effects.

Comment: @Pointy, interesting, just applied: http://jsperf.com/parseintx1/7

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a JavaScript engine expert by any means, or even a compiler expert, but I'm pretty sure that it boils down to the fact that the compiler can tell that this:

```
var a = "123";
a = a * 1;
```

is really exactly the same as:

```
var a = 123;
```

Because "a" is a local variable, and is unused from the point of its initialization to that `* 1` expression, there's no point generating code to carry out the operation at all. After that point, the compiler may also be able to tell that there's no way that "a" can "escape" from the function, so there's really no point doing *anything*; that is, it may be that the `* 1` test ends up with something equivalent to what you'd get from:

```
function() {}
```

In the `parseInt()` case, however, the compiler can't be sure that `parseInt()` is really `parseInt()`, as it may have been redefined. Thus, it has to generate code to make the function call.

Comment: And maybe FF is less efficient in optimizing the `parseInt` test compared to Chrome. Did anyone test in IE ;~)? Ah yes, same as firefox for the original test (IE9).

Answer (score 2):

It has to be the test setup, since [this version](http://jsperf.com/parseintx1/7) gives the expected result in Firefox too. The thing, in your setup I think, is that `parseInt` is applied (well, in FF at least) in every iteration to every variable, whereas the conversion from `String` to `Number` may be applied the first iteration in the multiplication test, after which the variables are numeric and multiplication needs no conversion anymore.

In version 7 the variables are assigned in the test setup, and the test assigns new variables at every iteration. Now both tests have 'equal changes', and `parseInt` outperforms the multiplication test.

After inspecting the test in IE[8,9] and seeing its results look like those of FF I think there's an explanation for the Chrome results: I'm pretty sure Chrome/Webkit has a better optimization in the first version of the test (especially the `parseInt` part), which gives a better result for `parseInt` there. It may be the precompilation of (parts of) the code in the [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29) engine, used in those browsers.

Comment: Yes I think this might be an alternative explanation to mine.  I don't know exactly how jsperf sets up the test code.

Comment: Looking at this version of the test, it appears `*1` is still better in Firefox, and `parseInt()` wins in Chrome (and overall for speed).